# Eclipse: Format: How to keep eclipse from adding brackets inside if

Tags: eclipse, formatting

We use the format function of eclipse, and it works mostly well.
But every time it formats it changes something like this

```
if (position != null && BtmList.useBtmListForPositionType(position.getTyp()) &&
                position.getElementUuid() != null && !ElementType.ELEMENT_TYPE_R.equals(position.getTyp())) {
```

into

```
if ((position != null) && BtmList.useBtmListForPositionType(position.getTyp()) &&
                ((position.getElementUuid() != null) && !ElementType.ELEMENT_TYPE_R.equals(position.getTyp())))
```

It just adds a lot of braces that are not needed, and i can't find an option to turn it off.

I went to Window -> Preferences -> Java -Formatter and serached through the profile, but it doensn't seem to be there.
Then is searched under Action on Save, but still no luck.

Comment: It seems you have as _Save Action_ the clean-up _Code Style > Expressions > Use parentheses in expressions_ set to _Always_. If you didn't overlooked it in _Window > Preferences_, then it's probably a project specific _Save Action_ (_Project > Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions_).